# How does one fix a MBP trackpad which is slightly tipping/popping out from its base?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I want to fix my trackpad for my mid-2010 MBP. It's partially tipping upwards on the left-hand side. Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it a relatively easy job? will I need to buy a new trackpad? or is there a way to fix the current one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a swollen battery. Same thing happened to me last year, fixed when I replaced the dying battery.

Comment: Yep I googled that. Dag had this battery for maybe a year 1 1/2.